# Eclipse Kepler Content Assist Customization

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to customize how it searches for methods and fields, for example:

```
JFileChooser j = new JFileChooser();
j. //I begin to type here and then it lists all the different methods and fields
```

Now lets say for example I begin to type Dialogue, the Content Assist will show `DIALOG_TITLE_CHANGED_PROPERTY` but it will not show `ShowOpenDialog` is there a way to customize the Content Assist so that it will more liberally search the middle and end of the words rather than just the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open bug/feature request in the eclipse bug tracker for that: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350000

It is mentioned that this feature is included in the [Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/) plug-in.

Comment: Installed the plugin had to fiddle with some of the settings but it appears to be doing exactly what I asked for. Thanks! Very very useful for classes with tons of methods and fields.